# Alert Box does not Pop up

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and presently reading jquery for dummies,and was trying to execute first example of the book:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”  
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>My Test Page</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
alert(jQuery(‘img’).attr(‘alt’));  
});  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<p>This is my test page.</p>  
 <img src= "images/home.gif" height="28" width="28" alt="This is a test  
image.">  
</body>  
</html>
```

But after executing this example,the alert box does not pop-up.

Comment: probably `jquery-1.7.2.js` is not loaded or missing in your local directory.

Comment: use double or single quotes for `jQuery('img').attr('alt'));` and not those funny ones

Comment: i didn't notice the funny ones. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('img').attr('alt'));
  });
</script>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: +1 Having the correct type of **quotes** makes a world of difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're using weird quotes (`‘ ’`): 
 <s>alert(jQuery(‘img’).attr(‘alt’));</s>

```
alert(jQuery('img').attr('alt'));
```

Or with double quotes:

```
alert(jQuery("img").attr("alt"));
```

And you can't write javascript inside a script tag with `src` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(jQuery('img').attr('alt'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: They are not weird, they are smart :)

Comment: @VisioN. [Quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs). I guess they are just too "smart" for javascript to handle... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(jQuery(‘img’).attr(‘alt’));
});
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(jQuery(‘img’).attr(‘alt’));
});
</script>
```

Comment: @WouterH Because JavaScript is too dull for smart quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues going on.

First off, your example shows 'smart quotes'  (‘ / ’ ).  These aren't real quotes as understood by anything in the computing world.

Secondly, you are attempting to utilize script tags incorrectly.

You need to break them into multiple tags, one for the embed, and one for the inline:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(jQuery('img').attr('alt'));
});
</script>
```